# Achieving Image Scaling Effect in Jetpack Compose Horizontal Pager

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm working on a Jetpack Compose project where I'm using a HorizontalPager to create an infinite scroller of images. However, I'm having trouble achieving the specific image scaling effect I want. I want the center image to remain the same size, while the images on the left and right are scaled up while user slides the image.

I've tried adjusting the scaleFactor and scale in my code, but it's not producing the desired effect.

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun CustomSlider(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    sliderList: MutableList<String>,
    pagerPaddingValues: PaddingValues = PaddingValues(horizontal = 65.dp),
    imageCornerRadius: Dp = 16.dp,
    imageHeight: Dp = 240.dp,
) {
    val pageCount = Int.MAX_VALUE
    val pagerState = rememberPagerState(initialPage = pageCount / 2)

    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally, verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        ) {
            HorizontalPager(
                pageCount = pageCount,
                state = pagerState,
                contentPadding = pagerPaddingValues,
                modifier = modifier.weight(1f)
            ) { page ->
                val pageOffset = (pagerState.currentPage - page) + pagerState.currentPageOffsetFraction

   
                Box(modifier = modifier
                    .padding(10.dp)
                    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(imageCornerRadius))) {
                    AsyncImage(
                        model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current).scale(Scale.FILL)
                            .crossfade(true).data(sliderList[page % sliderList.size]).build(),
                        contentDescription = "Image",
                        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                        placeholder = painterResource(id = R.drawable.img),
                        modifier = modifier
                            .height(imageHeight)
                            .width(295.dp)
//                            .alpha(if (pagerState.currentPage == page) 1f else 0.5f)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Slider Image]

Comment: So you want that the images to the left and right to be smaller than the image that is in the middle, and as soon as an image is swiped to the middle, it should get bigger, right?

Comment: Yes, That's how I need it.

Answer (score 0):

```
val imageSize by animateFloatAsState(
    targetValue = if (pageOffset != 0.0f) 0.75f else 1f,
    animationSpec = tween(300))
```

and add this following code to AsyncImage modifier

```
.graphicsLayer {
    scaleX = imageSize
    scaleY = imageSize
 }
```